# при выполнении php artisan queue:work - ошибка UnexpectedValueException

Tags: laravel

```
Все команды работают запустил php artisan queue:work - и ошибка

UnexpectedValueException 

  The stream or file "/home/proect/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

  at vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:146
    142|             restore_error_handler();
    143|             if (!is_resource($stream)) {
    144|                 $this->stream = null;
    145| 
  > 146|                 throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The stream or file "%s" could not be opened in append mode: '.$this->errorMessage, $url));
    147|             }
    148|             stream_set_chunk_size($stream, $this->streamChunkSize);
    149|             $this->stream = $stream;
    150|         }

      +7 vendor frames 
  8   app/Exceptions/Handler.php:39
      Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::report()

      +2 vendor frames 
  11  [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleException()
```

Comment: Ну так и пишет же вам _The stream or file "/home/proect/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied_ . Нет доступа к лог-файлу. Прав не хватает. Посмотрите кто owner лог-файла и под каким юзером запускаете artisan

Comment: Dmitry Kozlov
а почему другие команды работают а при запуске к примеру php artisan make    и т.д
а php artisan queue:work и все с queue выдают такую ошибку?

Comment: видимо остальные команды ничего не пишут в лог во время своего выполнения

Comment: Dmitry Kozlov а где это посмотреть Посмотрите кто owner лог-файла и под каким юзером запускаете artisan

Comment: `ls -l /home/proect/www/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: так там не указано какой юзер просто ошибки